# How to Print all the columns in silverlight datagrid

Tags: silverlight

Im having 17 columns of datagrid in Silverlight. How can we print all columns in datagrid to print. Since there are more noumber of column, Im enabling Horizantal Scroolbar ,so tht user can scrollto lastcolumn easily.

During printing of silverligt datagrid, i could see contents which are shown in Silverlight Page , anything beyond scroll bar ,those images are cropped and not printed . Any solution for print all columns in datagrid even though beyond the screen width.

One more question, if i have datagrid with horizontal scrollbar enabled, datagrid.actualwidth always give 768 px but not from first column to last column width size

_mahens

Answer (score 1):

If you can wait six months for Silverlight 5, then you can completely control the print layout and format it exactly the way you want. Until then I'm not sure if there is anything you can do.

Answer (score 1):

You basically have 2 options here.

1. Shrink your datagrid using Scaling to make the whole grid fit on your page
2. Slice the grid into 2 grids (first half of the columns in the first grid, and the other half on the other), then print this as 2 separate pages. Of course you would have to take into account the height of the grid and print additional pages there as well if required.
   Difficult? Yes, but achievable :)